# Legal issues for selling software for a student on F-1 visa

Tags: united-states, income-tax, self-employment, sales-tax, f1-student-visa

A friend of mine is going to sell subscriptions for a SAAS software and he is on F-1 student visa as a non-resident alien. I have got a couple questions about legal issues:

- Does he need to form an LLC to sell software? He will be using bitcoin as payment system and a bank account won't be necessary.
- The software is related to his studies, which taxes is he supposed to pay?
- If he forms an LLC, does the company pay sales tax and he does not pay income tax?
- Is he allowed to get paid and sell software when he's still a student and not in OPT status?

Comment: I'd imagine this is too many complex questions all at once, and it's not really suitable for this site.  To be totally honest also, the chances of "friend" making any money to speak of are, really, zero.  I would simply go  .. ah, screw it, I'll put in an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here is a simple plan that works in real life for such garage-hobby undertakings:*

1. Simply go ahead and run this "product" using bitcoin. Just don't worry ***at all*** about any paperwork issues.
2. If, incredibly, "product" starts making - let's say - more than USD$100 a month.  Give it another three months.  Keep going as is.
3. If, incredibly, "product" starts making - let's say - more than USD$1000 a month.  **Only then, actually start the proceedings** to decide whether you need to do company formation, operate as an individual, set up in whatever jurisdiction, get started with IP, create an accounting system, address legal issues and so on.

Just go ahead and if, incredibly, it starts to get some traction -

## *only then do the setup.*

That's really the secret.

Just go for it, and only do the setup ***if anything happens***.

Enjoy !

Your specific detailed issues (what jurisdiction, pass-through entity or not, etc etc etc) are simply impossible to answer without a huge amount of detail and the facts you will gain once you start to have some transactions.

---

## So you're about to make a whole million bucks!

For those who are ***confident!*** their product is about to immediately gross enough money that they can have a downpayment on a tiny apartment in SF.

1. ***Go ahead and start*** the web site, mlm, whatever.
2. note that you'll ***only be taking in bitcoin anyways***
3. if actual money starts flowing in. you suddenly have 5, 10, 15 thousand USD worth of bitcoin.  ***only then ....***
4. only then would you spend money (ie, some of that money) setting up business entities in the relevant jurisdiction (Dubai or whatever), establishing the needed chain companies, beginning work on legal, etc etc (and as a tiny factor at the end of that chain, sure, a few advisors would sort out the best way to pay any taxes in the US / home country / whatever, taking in to account sundry issues such as visa status, etc etc).

So say tomorrow the 16th you launch this astounding web page, and by the 1st of March you have a huge downline and say $50,000 in bitcoin sitting there.

It is **absolutely totally OK** that you actually only **"set up the company then"**.  No problem at all.  One of your accountants in that company will then pay you (friend - whatever) money one way or the other (salary, disbursements - whatever your tax advisors recommend).

Comment: what if I told you I am scared that the product is going to make more than $100,000 in first month. What am I supposed to do if I make $10,000 in the first week. I want to get myself prepared to handle scaling.

Comment: I'd just laugh.

Comment: the key point to understand is that it's **completely ok** to only set it up "after" it's been running for (let's say) a few weeks.  that's the key here.  Enjoy

Comment: From a slightly more realistic perspective, *keep good records*. When you make slightly more than you spent setting up the enterprise, you don't want to end up losing money after tax because you can't find the invoice from (e.g.) the hosting provider, which would otherwise reduce your taxable income.

Comment: @RupertMorrish, all true but when you're making 10, 20, 50 thousand a day  by Wednesday - no worries!

Comment: So if I make $200,000 in U.S as a F-1 visa student without taking care of any legal problems. Do you still think I will be ok if I set everything up after that?

Comment: Absolutely no problem.  Note the last two paragraphs of the answer - read carefully - that's exactly what you're asking.